# How to convert a numeric year into day-month-year format in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a column called construction_year as numerical(int) year. I want to convert it to `dd-mm-yyyy` format in python. I have tried with datetime and pandas to_datetim and converting time stamp extracting the format but in vain.

Ex: I have year like 2013(int) I would like to convert it as 01-01-2013 in python 3.x.

Comment: As a string? Or as a datetime?

Comment: converting into date format dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 0):

## Into a string

If you want to convert it into a string, you can simply use:

```
convert_string = '01-01-{}'.format
```

and then use it like:

```
>>> convert_string(2013)
'01-01-2013'
```

## Into a datetime

If you want to convert it to a `datetime` object, you can simply use:

```
from datetime import date
from functools import partial

convert_to_date = partial(date,month=1,day=1)
```

Now `convert_to_date` is a function that converts a numerical `year` into a `date` object:

```
>>> convert_to_date(2013)
datetime.date(2013, 1, 1)
```